# Warning: Thunderbird can allow you to get to your mail using the provided configurations. However, you should contact your administrator or email prov

Tags: thunderbird

How do I get past this when configuring an account in Thunderbird? I want to have separate SMTP and IMAP servers. So far I've found Thunderbird much harder to use and configure than Outlook Express.

[image: imgur]

Comment: This is probably because either your IMAP or SMTP connection is not encrypted, and this presents a security risk you may want to resolve.  Can you [edit] and add more details about the setup you are using?

Comment: No, it gives a different error for that. They are encrypted, and forced to use SSL.

Comment: Oops, yes, that looks like a bug, the "Done" is disabled right?  What version are you using, there was a bug before that did this, but perhaps too rarely to get resolved.  If you `Change Settings` go to advanced, and configure manually does it do the same thing?

Comment: Version 17.0.3. When I click Change Settings, it just dismisses the dialog and goes back to the wizard.

Comment: It ended up corrupting my email accounts. I ended up with two accounts with the same name, and could not change the name or delete them! I had to manually edit prefs.js and delete anything new. I tried it again and not sure at which point, but it silently added an account in Tools > Account Settings. Then I was able to tweak it from there.

Comment: could you add this as an answer, others have had the same problem and would benefit from this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested,

It ended up corrupting my email accounts. I ended up with two accounts with the same name, and could not change the name or delete them! I had to manually edit prefs.js and delete anything new. I tried it again and not sure at which point, but it silently added an account in Tools > Account Settings. Then I was able to tweak it from there.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was what I found in another forum: it happens when you configure your second account and choose to use the same SMTP server you already configured for the first.

Try configuring a new SMTP server with the same parameters as the existing one.

Comment: Adding a reference link or additional information would be helpful